# Can't see parent directory when assigning subdirectory permissions

Tags: powershell, window

Sorry everyone, for bothering you. Currently I have a command line to enforce user permissions already working on the specified directory but I need your help on how to be able to see the higher level directory when the user accesses it. Because now, when the user accesses normally, he will not see a higher-level directory to access, he must access the available path, so it is very inconvenient. I just need to see the folders to access without editing or see another subfolder inside.

```
$acl = Get-Acl 'D:\TEST'
$path = "D:\TEST"
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("test.ktdv","write","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("test.ktnb","read","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path" -Recurse  -Force |
    Where-Object { ($_.Name -eq 'New Folder' -or $_.Name -eq 'B') } |
    Set-Acl -Aclobject $acl -Verbose
```

Comment: check the inhertiance flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags?view=net-6.0

Comment: ..and have a look at the [FileSystemRights Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights). The user(s) should have at least `ListDirectory` pernmissions on the parent folder to be able to read the contents of that directory.